# Clean duplicate phone numbers in R dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

We have a dataframe with a `Phone` column that has phone numbers, however phone numbers are duplicated in many of the columns:

```
structure(list(Title = c("Head Coach", "Athletic Trainer", "Head Coach", 
                         "Assistant Coach", "Student Assistant", "Head Men's Basketball Coach", "Coach"
), Phone = c("(904) 256-7242\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(904) 256-7242", 
             "256-765-5020\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t256-765-5020", 
             NA, "765.285.8142\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t765.285.8142", 
             "", "549-5849\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t549-5849", "516-302-1039"
)), row.names = c(1L,2L, 3L,4L,5L,6L,7L ), class = "data.frame")

                        Title                                                                              Phone
1                  Head Coach (904) 256-7242\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(904) 256-7242
2            Athletic Trainer     256-765-5020\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t256-765-5020
3                  Head Coach                                                                               <NA>
4             Assistant Coach     765.285.8142\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t765.285.8142
5           Student Assistant                                                                                   
6 Head Men's Basketball Coach             549-5849\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t549-5849
7                       Coach                                                                       516-302-1039
```

The correct output would remove phone number duplicates:

```
structure(list(Title = c("Head Coach", "Athletic Trainer", "Head Coach", 
                         "Assistant Coach", "Student Assistant", "Head Men's Basketball Coach", "Coach"
), Phone = c("(904) 256-7242", 
             "256-765-5020", 
             NA, "765.285.8142", 
             "", "549-5849", "516-302-1039"
)), row.names = c(1L,2L, 3L,4L,5L,6L,7L ), class = "data.frame")
```

Typically I would share our progress on this, but quite frankly we are lost as to how to even get started on this. Seems like a very difficult problem especially given (a) the `\r\n\t\t\t\` that appear in the strings, (b) that there are NA and missing values and (c) not every row is duplicated, (d) different formats (some area codes, some with ., some with -, some with ()). Any recommendations on how to clean this column?

Answer (score 1):

```
 df$Phone = sub('\r.*', '', df$Phone)

                        Title          Phone
1                  Head Coach (904) 256-7242
2            Athletic Trainer   256-765-5020
3                  Head Coach           <NA>
4             Assistant Coach   765.285.8142
5           Student Assistant               
6 Head Men's Basketball Coach       549-5849
7                       Coach   516-302-1039
```

Comment: Dear Onyambu, may I ask what `\r` matches here?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR `\r` is a carriage return. The data as provided does have the carriage return immediately after the phone number

Comment: Oh I understand, Thank you very much and it's been a while :)

Answer (score 0):

We could remove the whitespace with `gsub`, split at the delimiter created (`,`) and extract the first element

```
df1$Phone <- sapply(strsplit(gsub("[\r\n\t]+", ",", df1$Phone), ","), \(x) x[1])
```

-output

```
df1$Phone
[1] "(904) 256-7242" "256-765-5020"   NA   
[4] "765.285.8142"   NA               "549-5849"       "516-302-1039"
```

---

Or another option is `trimws` - specify the `whitespace` to match the one or more `[\r\n\t]` followed by other characters (`.*`)

```
trimws(df1$Phone, whitespace = "[\r\n\t]+.*")
[1] "(904) 256-7242" "256-765-5020"   NA  
[4] "765.285.8142"   ""               "549-5849"       "516-302-1039"
```